# How to implement live camera streaming in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am developing one iphone application in which I want to implement live camera streaming feature.I dont know how it possible and which freamwork I have to used.
Please give me advice for this query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also want to implement this, Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the AVFoundation.framework for camera streaming. Specifically the classes AVCaptureSession, AVCaptureDevice, and AVCaptureDeviceInput.

There is a Technical Q&A on doing this here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1702.html